# console result is not correct? when call getUrlParam function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Utils.js:

```
// getUrlParam() is get location function

getUrlParam(name){
    let queryString = window.location.search.split('?')[1],
        reg = new RegExp('(^|&)' + name + '=([^&]*)(&|$)'),
        result = queryString.match(reg);
    return decodeURIComponent(result[2])
}
```

Login Component:

```
class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            redirect: _utils.getUrlParam('redirect')
        }
    }
}

// _user.login() is backend login interface
// UserInfo include username and password

login(){
    _user.login(UserInfo).then((res) => {
        console.log(this.state.redirect)
    })
}
```

when i click "button", if location is "http://localhost:8088/login?redirect=%2Fcategory%2Findex", i want get the result is '/category/index' , but now i get result is '/'? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression a bit:

```js
var name = 'redirect';
var reg = new RegExp('(^|&)' + name + '=([^&]*)(&|$)');

var url = 'http://localhost:8088/login?redirect=%2Fcategory%2Findex';

var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
var match = queryString.match(reg);

console.log(decodeURIComponent(match[2]));
```

Comment: thank you very much! i can ask you why "+ name+" not get "/category/index"? thanks!